# Create codebuild project on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, aws-codebuild

This is the first time I create a code build project, but I dont know how to fix this below errors

```
User: arn:aws:iam::461553956168:user/binhtl-dev is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource: policy CodeBuildBasePolicy-Chesyblog-us-east-2
```

I try to create policy and attach for IAM user like below, but didn't work

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your uses does not have the rights to create a IAM policy. You should ask those permission or use a existing role and policy and assign that to the codebuild project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "iam:CreatePolicy" policy in your Action array in your policy statement json.